# Update nested data arrays of object (Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I have an issue with updating the immutable redux and quite nested data. Here's an example of my data structure and what I want to change. If anyone could show me the pattern of accessing this update using ES6 and spread operator I would be thankful.

```
const formCanvasInit = {
  id: guid(),
  fieldRow: [{
    id: guid(),
    fieldGroup: [
      { type: 'text', inputFocused: true }, // I want to change inputFocused value
      { type: 'text', inputFocused: false },
    ],
  }],

  // ...
};
```

Comment: I don't know anything about redux, but as you says it's Immutable, which mean you cannot modify or updating it... :D

Comment: Immutability in this context means we should not modify data directly, therefore we have to make a shallow copy first then we can modify the copied data. 

Comment: You don't want a shallow copy; you want a true copy, or edits like this to nested attributes will permeate to the original state, which can lead to issues in flux architecture.

Comment: @treyhakanson 
Yes, I mean Copying All Levels of Nested Data.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of  [How to update a nested state in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-a-nested-state-in-react/43041334#43041334)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, assuming the data is set up exactly as shown, with the given array indices:

```
const newData = {
   ...formCanvasInit,
   fieldRow: [{
      ...formCanvasInit.fieldRow[0],
      fieldGroup: [
         { ...formCanvasInit.fieldRow[0].fieldGroup[0], inputFocused: newValue },
         ...formCanvasInit.fieldRow[0].fieldGroup.slice(1, formCanvasInit.fieldRow[0].fieldGroup.length)
      ]
   }]
};
```

If index of the element to be changed is to be determined dynamically, you'll need to use functionality such as `filter` to find and remove the array element you're updating, and then spread the corresponding subarrays by editing the structure of the call to `slice`.

Comment: This solution seems to be working, thanks mate. I really appreciate your help.  Would you mind to give me a reference to read? I really need to learn this particular thing.

Comment: Not a problem; it's a bit length, but the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) on the spread operator covers basically everything you'd need to know. Here's a quicker read from the [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) as well

Comment: I don't know if this works if we are trying to update something thats not the first index of fieldRow

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Immutability Helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)

I think in your structure, like this

```
let news = update(formCanvasInit, {
  fieldRow: [{
    fieldGroup: [
     { $set: {type: "number", inputFocused: false}}
    ]
  }]
})
```

I've tried it
[Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJmT3.png)

Comment: Thanks, this one also works, I might consider refactoring my codebase using this helper. I have a question, how to get the inputFocused value, because i want to make a toggle for inputFocused, when a certain action is happening. 

I want to do something like //... inputFocused: !inputFocused

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a longer solution but might help you as your redux state grows. I've also changed some of the values in the original state to make a clearer explanation.

```
const formCanvasInit = {
  id: 'AAAAXXXX',
  fieldRow: [
    {
      id: 1001,
      fieldGroup: [
        {type: 'text1', inputFocused: true}, // I want to change inputFocused value
        {type: 'text2', inputFocused: false},
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1002,
      fieldGroup: [
        {type: 'text3', inputFocused: true},
        {type: 'text4', inputFocused: true},
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// the id of the field row to update
const fieldRowID = 1001;
// the value of the field type to update
const fieldTypeValue = 'text1';
const fieldRow = [...formCanvasInit.fieldRow];

// obtain the correct fieldRow object
const targetFieldRowIndex = formCanvasInit.fieldRow.findIndex(fR => fR.id === fieldRowID);
let fieldRowObj = targetFieldRowIndex && formCanvasInit.fieldRow[targetFieldRowIndex];

// obtain that fieldRow object's fieldGroup
const fieldGroup = [...fieldRowObj.fieldGroup];

// obtain the correct object in fieldGroup
const fieldIndex = fieldGroup.findIndex(fG => fG.type === fieldTypeValue);
const fieldToChange = fieldIndex && fieldGroup[fieldIndex];

// replace the old object in selected fieldGroup with the updated one
fieldGroup.splice(fieldIndex, 1, {...fieldToChange, inputFocused: false});

// update the target fieldRow object
fieldRowObj = {...fieldRowObj, fieldGroup};

// replace the old fieldGroup in selected fieldRow with the updated one
fieldRow.splice(targetFieldRowIndex, 1, fieldRowObj);

// create the new formCanvasInit state
const newFormCanvasInit = {...formCanvasInit, fieldRow};
```

Comment: I'm a little bit overwhelmed seeing this long code, but it helps me to think in a different way. I appreciate that

Comment: I'm a bit curious of why you need to store a input's focus state in the reducer. Can you manage this state using the input component's internal state instead?

Comment: Honestly, that's not the real data state that I want to use on my app, I just trying to nail the concept of immutability update. This question was one of my way to understand how people solve this kind of case, I want to start with the simplest one.